# Is it ok to reset database on running programs in acceptance testing?

Tags: ruby, microservices, acceptance-testing

I have a system of multiple ruby applications. Full stop and start of this system takes about 2 minutes. I decided to make my apps fault-tolerant to DB downs, so when I drop databases and restore them my apps don't fail.

Is it normal? Are there any pitfalls?

Comment: Why should it be bad? It's awesome, you have a resilient system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your schema changes, you still need to restart the Rails processes. The reason is that ActiveRecord caches column data during startup.

Comment: Forunately, schema not changes between scenarious.

Comment: Nice! That's the only pitfall that I've found.